# When using Google Analytics with a Chrome Extension, should page views be suppressed?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

Chrome makes it pretty easy to integrate Google Analytics in Chrome, but it seems to me that using it the way indicated here:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics.html

would cause your user numbers to be artificially inflated.

If you call trackPageview every time background.js is loaded, you'll get a new "unique visitor" every time the browser is left open for more than 30 minutes.

Should calls to trackPageView be made no more than once ever 24 hours to make sure you're only getting daily uniques?

What's the best way to interpret Google Analytics data for a Chrome extension?

Comment: Where do you get 30 minutes from? And why do you believe Analytics puts the responsibility of determining unique visitors on the client? It's hard to answer your question without understanding the unstated assumptions underlying it.

Comment: My understanding is that if Google Analytics detects a visitor to your site that hasn't visited in the last 30 minutes, they are considered a new unique visitor. Even if they aren't a unique visitor, it seems wrong in the extension case to report every load of background.js as a page view. In most cases, I think an extension developer cares about daily unique users.